# Laravel 5 send mail in contact form

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

I use Laravel 5.1 and want to send the admin of the page a mail with the content of a contact form.

In my .env file I added the following lines:

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=admintest@gmail.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=adminpassword
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
```

In my controller I have the following:

```
 Mail::send('Site::email', ['contactObject' => $contactObject], function ($message) use ($contactObject) {
        $message->from($contactObject->email, $contactObject->vorname)->subject('New contact!');

        $message->to('admintest@gmail.com');
    });
```

$contactObject == contains the form which was filled out in the form from the user

Desired result:
When admintest@gmail.com receive a email, the sender of the mail should be $contactObject->email

Actual result:
When admintest@gmail.com receive a email, the sender of the mail is admintest@gmail.com

Any ideas what goes wrong? Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Try This:

In Live server you have no need to configure any type of mail service.

You have to just use this:

```
MAIL_DRIVER=mail
```

AND remove this code:

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=admintest@gmail.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=adminpassword
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to just use in  .env file:

```
MAIL_DRIVER=mail
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=xyz@gmail.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=yourpassword
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
```

After change in .env file, restart service, or use command  **php artisan config:cache** and   **php artisan config:clear**.

Answer (score 0):

Have you configured the global from address in the config?

Specifically here: https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/config/mail.php#L49

Chances are that you've set that and it's just using that, making these values blank should let you override it.

Failing that, because you're using Gmail to send an email to Gmail, it's likely not letting you spoof the from and is indeed a security feature on their end.